# SQL Server query with Lead function is taking time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, lead

I am trying to execute below code which is taking too much time to execute.

```
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.DeviceID, a.SubscriberLoginID ORDER BY a.GPSCommandID) Row,
    a.DeviceId,
    SubscriberLoginID,
    CabLatitude, CabLongitude,
    LEAD(CabLatitude) OVER (PARTITION BY a.DeviceId, SubscriberLoginID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, GPSDateTime)) NextLat,
    LEAD(CabLongitude) OVER (PARTITION BY a.DeviceId, SubscriberLoginID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, GPSDateTime)) NextLong,
    MeterStatusId,
    LEAD(MeterStatusId) OVER (PARITITON BY a.DeviceId, SubscriberLoginID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME,GPSDateTime)) NextStatus,
    a.GPSDateTime,
    LEAD(GPSDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY a.DeviceId, SubscriberLoginID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, GPSDateTime)) NextGPSDateTime,
    a.LocationName,
    LEAD(LocationName) OVER (PARTITION BY a.DeviceId, SubscriberLoginID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, GPSDateTime)) NextLocationName
FROM    
    tblGPSDataDetail a WITH(NOLOCK) 
JOIN
    dbo.tblDeviceMaster tdm WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.DeviceID = tdm.DeviceID 
                                         AND CityID = 3
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, GPSDateTime), 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE() - 1, 101)
```

Comment: How do you know that it is the `lead()` that is causing the performance issue?  Why would you be storing `GPSDateTime` as a string?  That is probably the root cause of the performance issues.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. In my table GPSDateTime Column is varchar. Cause of that I was storing into varchar. Now I came to know my Mistake. I have made changes into my code. CONVERT(DATE,GPSDateTime) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()-1)

Comment: [WITH(NOLOCK) is not a turbo button](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Also: 1. [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), 2. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Which column belong to which table?